# How not to erase an iterator (from "Effective STL")

Tags: c++, containers

I have been reading effective stl. I got stuck here:

```
assoccontainer<int> c
for(container<int>::iterator i=c.begin();i!=c.end();++i)
  if(badvalue(*i))
    c.erase(i);
```

What is the problem with the given code? I don't understand the explanation there.

I have other question too:

1. What does an `assoccontainer` mean? I can't find any related article.
2. Is `badvalue` some kind of a keyword?

Comment: My guess would be that you modify the container while you are iterating through the set. Modifications should be done using the iterator.

Comment: This question is using a sort of pseudo code to make a point. And when you know the point you also know the answer to the question. The point is in calling `erase` on an `iterator`.

Comment: A better title for the question might be `Book example uses classes I've never heard of`, or `Example showing problem with erasing iterators doesn't make sense`.

Comment: @jogojapan Far better than my suggestions. Naming things is a key skill.

Comment: @PeterWood Oops, I hadn't actually noticed your comment. Sorry, but yes, I hope the title is ok now. Anyone, feel free to improve further, of course.

Answer (score 5):

> What does an assoccontainer mean?

It means some kind of associative container, such as `std::set`. Note that it's printed in italics, meaning that it's not real code, but a placeholder for the actual container type.

> Is 'badvalue' some kind of a keyword?

No, it's meant to be a function defined by the program to determine whether a value should be removed from the container. It's introduced on the previous page, where it says "let's eliminate every object for which the following predicate returns true".

> What is the problem with the given code

That's explained in the book, immediately after the code sample. `erase(i)` invalidates the iterator - meaning that you can no longer do anything with it - so doing `++i` immediately afterwards gives undefined behaviour. Instead, you need to use the code from later on the same page:

```
for (AssocContainer<int>::iterator i = c.begin(); i != c.end(); /* nothing */) {
    if (badValue(*i)) c.erase(i++);
    else ++i;
}
```

which increments `i` *before* erasing and invalidating its old value.

Comment: Interesting. How is `c.erase(i++);` different from `c.erase(i);i++;`?

Comment: @Dialecticus: The first calls `erase` on the old value *after* incrementing `i`, so `i` itself is not invalidated. The second gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: suppose the elements are 1,2,3,4,5 let us say that iterator points to 3. If c.erase(i++) is given then 4 is deleted. Where as when the second   code is given, 3 is deleted.

Comment: @Saikiran: No, in both cases `3` is erased, since post-increment (`i++`) returns the value *before* incrementing. The difference is that in the first case, `i` ends up referring to `4`; in the second, it ends up invalidated.

Comment: Didn't know I can rely on everything in argument list being resolved before the function call. I always used temp iterator in similar cases. We learn something every day :)

Comment: @MikeSeymour don't you think that the second code is efficient? Because say the elements are 1,2,3 and the bad element is 2, and now the iterator stop at 2, now instead of deleting 2 it'd delete 3(because of ++i)

Comment: @Saikiran: If you want to stop after erasing a single element, then indeed the first code (with a `break` after `erase`) is more efficient. However, if you want to carry on and erase all elements that satisfy the predicate, then you have to use the second version since the first does not work. Broken code is never more efficient than working code.

Answer (score 2):

`assoccontainer` and `badvalue` are irrelevant for the main question. Just pretend `assoccontainer` is some container, and `badvalue` is some function returning bool. Main problem is using an iterator after it has been used to remove an element. After the `erase` iterator is invalid and can no longer be used.

Answer (score 0):

assoccontainer is the equivalent of a dictionary or a hashmap, though the author (Scott Meyers?) may have been using it in a generic sense. AFAIK, there is no container in the STL by that name; replace that with std::map. I guess that should do the trick.

You will find more information about it here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_containers_(C%2B%2B)

It has a neat example for counting occurrences of a string.

Most probably Scott Meyers meant badvalue() to be a user-defined function that figures out whether the value de-referenced using the iterator is valid or not.

HTH.